# Best practice to copy files to a new folder in SVN

Tags: svn, version-control

I am trying to copy bunch of folders to a new folder and want to commit the files in the new folder.

the new folder is called `test` but when I tried to `svn add test/`, it gave me `'test' is already under version control` error. I need to `commit` the new test folder and need the files under that folder in version. What is the best practice to do this?

Comment: It sounds like `test` is not really "new".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't copy and then use [`svn add`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.add.html). This will create a completely separate set of files and the files will have no relationship with each other. Instead, use [`svn copy` (aka `svn cp`)](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.copy.html). This way, you can merge changes that take place on the original set to your test set.

Also, make it a complete branch while you're at it. Branching in Subversion is [light](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.branchmerge.using.html#svn.branchmerge.using.create.dia-1) and [quick](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.branchmerge.using.html#svn.branchmerge.using.create). Branch the whole project as your test area. Don't just do a few directories. This way, you can treat it like an entire project.

Finally, make sure you're directory doesn't already exist. This is what your error message is telling you.